# Line-of-Sight method of simple code transmitting for outdoors

Tags: batteries, signal, infrared

I'm trying to determine the best way to do this. Basically I'm trying to design a system that would transmit a signal containing a simple code to allow the receiver to identify the source device. It needs to work only with line of sight. Like laser-tag. My first thought was IR, but I'm worried that this would not perform well in sunlight. Whatever the system uses must be able to work in direct sunlight, and must be able to run on common batteries. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sunlight in optics represents a large but slow moving dc signal. This is easily got rid of by high pass filtering the received optical signal. Providing the level or intensity of the sunlight doesn't "saturate" the receiving device, all you need to ensure is that the data transmitted is modulated at a "carrier" frequency of several kHz or more. Thisis usually how this problem is overcome. Modulating the data means it carries no slow or dc component that is vital for data transmission integrity.

Comment: `Manchester Encoding` is a good place to start: that's how consumer TV remote controls usually operate.